# Create a new Mac Terminal command to copy folder

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

How can I create a new terminal command that copies a folder (this will always be the same folder) and it's contents to either the current directory (if no path is supplied) or to the path supplied.

This command should take the following parameters:

1. Name of the new folder to copy the contents to (i.e. `mkdir
   myNewFolder`)
2. The path of the directory in which to create the new folder and paste the contents into.

I'd like to end up with something like this:

```
$ createsite newFolderName ./Desktop/sites/
```

I don't really know where to start with this. So any help is appreciated

Comment: Let me get this straight.. You want to copy a folder to another path or you want to create a folder in a certain path?

Comment: I'd like to copy the folder to the current directory or, if a path is supplied I want to copy the folder to that path.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't simply want to use `mkdir -p` and then a `cp`, then you may as well create a fairly robust function to copy `it wall always be the same folder` to the directory name given by `dirnm` as the **first argument** (in the current working directory if no second argument given) or to `/destpath/dirnm` if a path representing `destpath` is given in argument as the **second argument**.

In forming the paths involved, you will need to check for (and remove) leading and trailing `'/'` characters in `dirnm` and any trailing `'/'` in `destpath. You then attempt to create`destpath/dirnm`as given and on success copy`it wall always be the same folder`to`destpath/dirnm`(with the`-a` option, or as desired). On failure, throw error and return. The following is one approach to such a function:

```
mkdircp ()
{
    srcdir="NameOfDirToCopy"    ## the name of the dir you always copy (w/full path)

    [ -d "$srcdir" ] || {       ## validate srcdir exists
        printf "error: source directory '%s' does not exist.\n" "$srcdir"
        return 1
    }

    [ -z $1 ] && {              ## validate that required dirnm given
        printf "usage: mdcp dirnm [destpath (default ./)]\n";
        return 1
    };

    ## trim leading/trailing '/' from dirnm
    [ ${1:0:1} == '/' ] && dirnm="${1:1}" || dirnm="$1"
    [ ${1:(-1)} == '/' ] && dirnm="${dirnm%/}"

    ## if destpath given, trim trailing '/' & set destdir
    if [ -n "$2" ]; then
        [ ${2:(-1)}x == '/x' ] && destpath="${2%/}" || destpath="$2"
        [ -n "$2" ] && destdir="${destpath}/${dirnm}"
    else
        destdir="./$dirnm"    ## default destdir in ./
    fi

    ## create destdir & validate or throw error
    [ -d "$destdir" ] || mkdir -p "$destdir"
    [ -d "$destdir" ] || {
        printf "error: unable to create destdir '%s'. (check permissions)\n" "$destdir"
        return 1
    }

    ## copy (-recursive -archive) "$srcdir" "$destdir"
    printf "copying:  %s -> %s\n" "$srcdir" "$destdir"
    # cp -a "$srcdir" "$destdir"    ## (uncomment for actual copy )
}
```

I would include the function in your `~/.bashrc` (or ~/.profile) or you can manually enter/export it in your current shell. I would also create a convenient `alias` to cut down typing following the declaration in `.bashrc` like:

```
alias mdcp='mkdircp'
```

With the alias, the use is:

```
mdcp dirnm [destpath (default: ./)]
```

To copy `it wall always be the same folder` to `destpath/dirnm`. Let me know if you have any questions or need to adjust things a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a function. Add these lines to your `~/.profile` (or, if not on OSX, to your `~/.bashrc`):

```
createsite(){
    ## Change this to point to the folder you want to copy
    source="/path/to/source/folder"

    ## If no parameters were given, copy to the current directory
    if [ $# -eq 0 ];
    then    
        cp -rv "$source" .
    ## If an argument was given
    elif [ $# -eq 1 ]
    then
        ## Create the directory. The -p suppresses error messages
        ## in case the directory exists.
        mkdir "$1"
        ## Copy
        cp -rv "$source" "$1"/
    ## If more than one was given, something's wrong.
    else
        echo "Usage: $0 [target_directory]";
        exit 1;
    fi
}
```

Then, open a new terminal and you can run

```
createsite foo
```

Which will copy the contents of `/path/to/source/folder` into the newly created directory `foo`. Note that this is a very simplistic approach and won't warn you if the directory exists or if files will be overwritten.

Or, just run `createsite` and it will copy to the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

rsync is a command that could help you. It can synchronize 2 folders efficiently by looking at differences between them. It also works over the network.

```
rsync source destination
```

Either source or destination can be expressions, like `pwd` or ${HOME}; relative, like . ; or fixed, like /tmp

For more info read the fine manual pages:

```
man rsync
```